# How to reset list to blank using javascript in Oracle apex

Tags: javascript, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1, oracle-apex-20.2, oracle-apex-20.1

I have a `select list` component in Oracle apex and one button

Select list drop down as below values I can choose any one

-

- A
- B
- C

On button click I have written a java script

```
if $('#P1_DROPDOWN').val() == 'A'
{
   alert.message('A value is selected') 
}
else
{
   apex.item.setvalue(index[0])  -- blank 
   or 
   reset the list to none selected 
}
```

How do I reset the List item to none o original state

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example for a select list that has "Display Null Value" set to "Yes" and no value for "Null Return Value".

```
if (apex.item( "P1_DROPDOWN" ).getValue() == 'A') {
    alert('a was clicked');
} else {
    apex.item( "P1_DROPDOWN" ).setValue( "" );
}
```

If there is a return value for the Null value, then change the `setValue` accordingly.

Side Note:  Instead of clearing the selected value a validation indicating why the selected value is not the correct one might give a better user experience.